# How do I terminate this sample Swing application using WindowEvent?

Tags: java, swing

I'm still new to this, and I would be very grateful if you could provide detailed explanation on its workings.
The aim of this project is to:

- have one application class, and another class for JFrame.
- The application would create two user interfaces.
- Both firstUI and secondUI needs to be closed, while each has its own print message which needs to be invoked separately. Then this application would terminate.

```
/**
 * Main application start
 */
public class AppStart {

    public void startThread() {
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AppUI secondUI = new AppUI();
            }
        });
        t2.run();
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println("Just waiting for user input..");
        Scanner keyScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userIn = keyScan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("This should not output");
    }

    public AppStart() {
        AppUI firstUI = new AppUI();
        startThread();
        doSomethingElse();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppStart appStartup = new AppStart();

    }

    /**
     * User Interface
     */
    class AppUI {

        public void justPrint() {
            System.out.println("UI closed");
            // should output one of each for firstUI and secondUI
            // then terminate all AppUI and AppStart
        }

        public AppUI() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(150, 150);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            // WindowListener; do action before closing
            frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                    formWindowClosing(evt);
                }
            });
        }

        public void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            justPrint();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *Both firstUI and secondUI needs to be closed,* - an application should only have a single JFrame as the parent window. For child windows you can use a JDialog and specify the parent as the owner. When you close the parent the child will also be closed. If you close the child only the child is closed.

Comment: Don't mix a GUI with console I/O. It is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Your creation of a new thread shows a fundamentally wrong understanding of how user interfaces work. Using a different thread here, has no effect at all.